# unbound identifier in Racket

Tags: compiler-construction, racket

I have this code sample

```
#lang racket

(provide parse
         desugar
         eval
         load-defs
         repl)

(struct eq-exp (lhs rhs) #:transparent)
(struct and-exp (operands) #:transparent)
(struct or-exp (operands) #:transparent)
(struct int-exp (val) #:transparent)
(struct arith-exp (op lhs rhs) #:transparent)
(struct var-exp (id) #:transparent)
(struct let-exp (ids vals body) #:transparent)
(struct lambda-exp (id body) #:transparent)
(struct app-exp (fn arg) #:transparent)
(struct fun-val (id body env) #:transparent)
(struct bool-exp (val) #:transparent)
(struct if-exp (bool-exp true-exp false-exp) #:transparent)
(struct sub-exp (lhs rhs) #:transparent)


(define (parse sexp)
  (match sexp
    [(? integer?)
     (int-exp sexp)]
    [(? boolean?)
     (bool-exp sexp)]
     
    [(list '-' lhs rhs)
     (sub-exp (parse lhs) (parse rhs))]
    [(list '=' lhs rhs)
     (eq-exp (parse lhs) (parse rhs))]
    [(list (and op (or '+ '*)) lhs rhs)
     (arith-exp (symbol->string op) (parse lhs) (parse rhs))]
    [(list 'and exps)
     (and-exp (map parse exps))]
    [(list 'or exps)
     (or-exp (map parse exps))]
    [(? symbol?)
     (var-exp sexp)]
    [(list 'let (list (list id val) ...) body)
     (let-exp (map parse id) (map parse val) (parse body))]
    [(list 'lambda (list ids ...) body)
     (lambda-exp ids (parse body))]
    [(list 'if bool true-expr false-expr)
     (if-exp (parse bool) (parse true-expr) (parse false-expr))]
    [(list f args ...)
     (app-exp (parse f) (map parse args))]
    [_ (error (format "Can't parse: ~a" sexp))]))

(define (desugar exp)
  (match exp
    ((arith-exp op lhs rhs)
     (arith-exp op (desugar lhs) (desugar rhs)))
    ((let-exp ids vals body)
     (let-exp ids (map desugar vals) (desugar body)))
    ((lambda-exp ids body)
     (foldr (lambda (id lexp) (lambda-exp id lexp))
            (desugar body)
            ids))
    ((app-exp f args)
     (foldl (lambda (id fexp) (app-exp fexp id))
            (desugar f)
            (map desugar args)))
    (_ exp)))

(define (eval expr [env '()])
  (match expr
    [(int-exp val) val]
    [(bool-exp val) val]
    [(arith-exp "+" lhs rhs) (+ (eval lhs env) (eval rhs env))]
    [(arith-exp "*" lhs rhs) (* (eval lhs env) (eval rhs env))]
    [(var-exp id)
     (let ([pair (assoc id env)])
       (if pair (cdr pair) (error (format "~a not bound!" id))))]
    [(let-exp (list (var-exp id) ...) (list val ...) body)
     (let ([vars (map cons id (map (lambda (v) (eval v env)) val))])
       (eval body (append vars env)))]
    [(lambda-exp id body)
     (fun-val id body env)]
    [(sub-exp lhs rhs) (- (eval lhs env) (eval rhs env))]
    [(eq-exp lhs rhs) (= (eval lhs env) (eval rhs env))]
    [(and-exp operands) (andmap (lambda (operand) (eval operand env)) operands)]
    [(or-exp operands) (ormap (lambda (operand) (eval operand env)) operands)]
    [(app-exp f arg)
     (match-let ([(fun-val id body clenv) (eval f env)]
                 [arg-val (eval arg env)])
       (eval body (cons (cons id arg-val) clenv)))]
    [(if-exp bool true-expr false-expr)
     (if (eval bool env)
         (eval true-expr env)
         (eval false-expr env))]
    [_ (error (format "Can't evaluate: ~a" expr))]))

(define (load-defs filename)
  (let* ([sexps (file->list filename)]
         [fn-names (map (compose first second) sexps)])
    fn-names))

(define (repl [filename #f])
  (let loop ([env (if filename (load-defs filename) '())])
    (let ([stx (desugar (parse (read)))])
      (when stx
        (println (eval stx env))
        (loop env)))))

(repl) ; Start the REPL
```

Running this code successfully should print nothing on console.
When I run this code it throws the error

```
mp3.rkt:32:21: lhs: unbound identifier
  in: lhs
  location...:
   mp3.rkt:32:21
```

I am not sure where things are going wrong, but I suspect this is the place

```
(define (parse sexp)
  (match sexp
    [(? integer?)
     (int-exp sexp)]
    [(? boolean?)
     (bool-exp sexp)]
     
    [(list '-' lhs rhs)
     (sub-exp (parse lhs) (parse rhs))]
    [(list '=' lhs rhs)
     (eq-exp (parse lhs) (parse rhs))]
    [(list (and op (or '+ '*)) lhs rhs)
     (arith-exp (symbol->string op) (parse lhs) (parse rhs))]
    [(list 'and exps)
     (and-exp (map parse exps))]
    [(list 'or exps)
     (or-exp (map parse exps))]
    [(? symbol?)
     (var-exp sexp)]
    [(list 'let (list (list id val) ...) body)
     (let-exp (map parse id) (map parse val) (parse body))]
    [(list 'lambda (list ids ...) body)
     (lambda-exp ids (parse body))]
    [(list 'if bool true-expr false-expr)
     (if-exp (parse bool) (parse true-expr) (parse false-expr))]
    [(list f args ...)
     (app-exp (parse f) (map parse args))]
    [_ (error (format "Can't parse: ~a" sexp))]))
```

Can anyone point me what I am doing wrong ?

I tried manipulating `[(list '-' lhs rhs) (sub-exp (parse lhs) (parse rhs))]` with `(define lhs 1)`. But it throws another exception.

Comment: Why did you write `'+` and `'*`, but `'-'` and `'='`? (And why are subtraction and equality treated differently from multiplication and addition?)

Answer (score 0):

`(list '-' lhs rhs)` is more normally written `(list '- 'lhs rhs)`. It's trying to match 2 symbols and then bind a third element to the variable `rhs`. Are you trying to match literal [characters](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/characters.html)? In Racket (And Scheme), those take the form `#\X`. So you need

```lisp
[(list #\- lhs rhs)
     (sub-exp (parse lhs) (parse rhs))]
```

and so on for the other cases.

Or if you're trying to match a literal string, use double quotes.

Or if you're trying to match symbols, it's just `'-`, no second single quote.

Comment: Looking deeper into your code, I think it's the third case.